# Post request in JupyterLab server extension breaks when calling imported function

Tags: python, typescript, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm working on creating a JupyterLab server-side extension from [this template](https://github.com/jupyterlab/extension-examples/tree/master/server-extension) and am having trouble calling an imported python function in the post method of handlers.py. The post request is sent from my index.ts file with a body containing the relative path of the active notebook when the user presses the "Measure Energy Usage" button. Sending it works fine if I leave out the call to measure_cell2.measure() in handlers.py. However, when I try to call that function, I get these errors on the right from the post request:

[image]

In the terminal running jupyter lab, I get this error:

[W 2021-07-13 12:42:47.633 ServerApp] 404 POST /jlab-ext-example/hello?1626198167480 (127.0.0.1) 7.70ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab/tree/jupyter_lab_ext/jlab_ext_example/nbtest2.ipynb

I know that `abs_path` is the correct path, because when I leave out the `measure` function call in handlers.py, simply print the path returned by `os.path.abspath`, and then run the `measure` function directly from the python console or the terminal using that path, it produces the desired output. The `post` method in handlers.py doesn't seem to be executing at all since `print(abs_path)` is never executed and it comes before the call to `measure`. What could be causing this error?

JupyterLab 3.0.16,
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-143-generic x86_64),
Python 3.9.5,
Node v14.8.0,
tsc 2.7.2

index.ts:

```
import {
  ILabShell,
  JupyterFrontEnd,
  JupyterFrontEndPlugin
} from '@jupyterlab/application';

import { IRetroShell } from '@retrolab/application';

import { ICommandPalette } from '@jupyterlab/apputils';

import { ILauncher } from '@jupyterlab/launcher';

import { requestAPI } from './handler';

import { ToolbarButton } from '@jupyterlab/apputils';

import { DocumentRegistry } from '@jupyterlab/docregistry';

import { INotebookModel, NotebookPanel } from '@jupyterlab/notebook';

import { IDisposable } from '@lumino/disposable';

import { Title, Widget } from '@lumino/widgets';

var nbPath: string; // Holds relative path of notebook to convert

// Create button on the toolbar
export class ButtonExtension implements DocumentRegistry.IWidgetExtension<NotebookPanel, INotebookModel> {
    
  constructor(app: JupyterFrontEnd) { 
      this.app = app;
  }
  
  readonly app: JupyterFrontEnd
  
  // Create the toolbar button
  createNew(panel: NotebookPanel, context: DocumentRegistry.IContext<INotebookModel>): IDisposable {

    let mybutton = new ToolbarButton({ 
      label: 'Measure Energy Usage',
      onClick: async () => {

        // Post request to Jupyter server containing relative
        // path to .ipynb file
        const dataToSend = { file: nbPath };
        try {
          const reply = await requestAPI<any>('hello', {
            body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
            method: 'POST'
          });
          console.log(reply);
        } catch (reason) {
          console.error(
            `Error on POST /jlab-ext-example/hello ${dataToSend}.\n${reason}`
          );
        }
      }
    });
    // Add the toolbar button to the notebook toolbar
    panel.toolbar.insertItem(10, 'MeasureEnergyUsage', mybutton);
    console.log("MeasEnerUsage activated");

    // The ToolbarButton class implements `IDisposable`, so the
    // button *is* the extension for the purposes of this method.
    return mybutton;
  }
}

/**
 * Initialization data for the server-extension-example extension.
 */
const extension: JupyterFrontEndPlugin<void> = {
  id: 'server-extension-example',
  autoStart: true,
  optional: [ILauncher],
  requires: [ICommandPalette],
  activate: async (
    app: JupyterFrontEnd
  ) => {
    console.log('JupyterLab extension server-extension-example is activated!');
    const your_button = new ButtonExtension(app);
    app.docRegistry.addWidgetExtension('Notebook', your_button);

    // Get name and relative path of active notebook tab
    var shell = app.shell as ILabShell | IRetroShell; 

    // When user changes tabs, update nbPath to be the relative path for current notebook
    const onTitleChanged = (title: Title<Widget>) => {
      nbPath = title.caption;
      nbPath = nbPath.slice(nbPath.indexOf("Path: ") + 6, nbPath.indexOf("Last Saved") - 1);
      console.log(nbPath);
    };

    // Watch for user changing tabs in JupyterLab
    shell.currentChanged.connect((_: any, change: any) => {
      const { oldValue, newValue } = change;

      if (oldValue) {
        oldValue.title.changed.disconnect(onTitleChanged);
      }
      if (newValue) {
        newValue.title.changed.connect(onTitleChanged);
      }
    });
  }
};

export default extension;
```

handlers.py:

```
import os
import json
import subprocess

from notebook.base.handlers import APIHandler
from notebook.utils import url_path_join

import tornado
from tornado.web import StaticFileHandler

import measure_cell2

class RouteHandler(APIHandler):
    # The following decorator should be present on all verb methods (head, get, post,
    # patch, put, delete, options) to ensure only authorized user can request the
    # Jupyter server

    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        self.finish(json.dumps({"data": "At the /jlab-ext-example/hello endpoint; finding and converting notebook"}))

    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def post(self):
        # receive .ipynb file name and relative path from index.ts on client-side
        # input_data is a dictionary with a key "file"
        input_data = self.get_json_body()
        # convert notebook to .py file with nbconvert
        subprocess.run(["jupyter", "nbconvert", input_data["file"], "--to", "script"])
        # get name and absolute path of converted .py file
        python_file_name = input_data["file"]
        extension_index = python_file_name.find(".")
        python_file_name = python_file_name[0:extension_index] + ".py"
        abs_path = os.path.abspath(python_file_name)
        print(abs_path)
        # measure code energy usage
        measure_cell2.measure(abs_path)
        # confirm conversion and measurement occurred
        data = {"greetings": "Converted notebook to the python file {}; now measuring energy usage".format(python_file_name)}
        self.finish(json.dumps(data))
        

def setup_handlers(web_app, url_path):
    host_pattern = ".*$"
    base_url = web_app.settings["base_url"]

    # Prepend the base_url so that it works in a JupyterHub setting
    route_pattern = url_path_join(base_url, url_path, "hello")
    handlers = [(route_pattern, RouteHandler)]
    web_app.add_handlers(host_pattern, handlers)

    # Prepend the base_url so that it works in a JupyterHub setting
    doc_url = url_path_join(base_url, url_path, "public")
    doc_dir = os.getenv(
        "JLAB_SERVER_EXAMPLE_STATIC_DIR",
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "public"),
    )
    handlers = [("{}/(.*)".format(doc_url), StaticFileHandler, {"path": doc_dir})]
    web_app.add_handlers(".*$", handlers)
```

measure_cell2.py:

```
import requests

def measure(file_path):
    base_url = 'http://localhost:9898'

    # send file and get ID 
    url_id = base_url + '/id'
    print(file_path)
    files = {'file': open(file_path, 'rb')} # opens file into buffer; rb = read buffer
    getID = requests.post(url_id, files=files)
    ID = getID.json().get('id')

    print("Running Code at ", file_path)
    print(ID)

    # send ID and get gpu results
    url_results_gpu = base_url + '/results/gpu?id={}'.format(ID)
    gpu_results = requests.get(url_results_gpu)
    print(gpu_results.text)

    # send ID and get cpu results
    url_results_cpu = base_url + '/results/cpu?id={}'.format(ID)
    cpu_results = requests.get(url_results_cpu)
    print(cpu_results.text)
```

Comment: If I were debugging this I would first add a print to `setup_handlers()` to confirm that it gets executed properly.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks--looks like setup_handlers is indeed not getting executed anymore when I try to call the `measure` function. I'm also getting this message in the console when I launch jupyter lab: `[W 2021-07-13 14:51:03.506 ServerApp] The module 'jlab_ext_example' could not be found. Are you sure the extension is installed?` When I try to do `jupyter labextension develop . --overwrite` after running `pip install -e .` I get  `ModuleNotFoundError: There is not a labextensions at .` Removing the call to the `measure` function makes both of these go away.

Comment: Does it go away after commenting out the `measure` call alone or after removing both the call and the import? What about a) wrapping the `measure` call into a `try-except` block and seeing if it does not raise an exception?

Comment: No, the import itself still creates the error even if I don't call the function.

Comment: Wild guess: `measure_cell2.py` not ending up installed correcyl? `requests` not in the virtual environment? you would need to wrap things in try-except to narrow it down.

Comment: Or add some prints in the `measure_cell2.py` file. Or use a debugger.